# Div Resive To Fit Text

Tags: html, css, resize, width

This is not necessary to get an answer, but it's more of a problem I've encountered.
Let's say I have a piece of text and I want that the div element that contains it to resize it width property proportionally to the amount of text. Is there a elegant way to do so?
I've read about min-width, but doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text typically flows to fill it's container. I don't think CSS is going to be the best way to accomplish this. The very concept is too dynamic for the limitations of CSS. The best way that I can think to do this would be to use javascript to adjust the width of the div based on the length of the string contained within.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same. I hoped there will be a way without JS. Thanks for confirming my suspicions.

Comment: No problem. When I first started developing, I hated going to JS for anything. I tried to keep things pure CSS wherever possible. But, this is just one of those things that is better accomplished with JS.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to implement a pure CSS solution if you have a target width/height ratio in mind.  Take a look at this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/how-to-maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-using-only-css) on the subject.

The trick is to add a parent `<div>` with `padding-bottom` applied.